# Ordered List margin problems (some with IE7)

Tags: html, css

1. I'm trying to create an OL that would stay in the same margin line as the title text above it;
   setting margin-left and padding-left as 0px took it too far to the left, out of my DIV (don't know why),
   so I've set them both at 11px; however at IE7 (with the IE10 console), there's a deviation of about 3px to the left.
2. another problem is that I couldn't find here a solution for decreasing the inner margin between each number and the text.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="left">
  <div id="marg">
  <p class="title">Title</p>
 <ol class="list">
   <li>aaa</li>
    <li>aaa<br>
        aaa<br>
        aaa
   </li>
 <li>aaa</li>
 </ol>
</div>
</div>
<br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid #DCD7D4;
    width: 740px;
    min-height: 680px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

#marg {
    margin: 10px;
}
.list {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 21px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 11px;     
}

.title {
    font-family: tahoma,arial;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #E25424;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
```

[image: both problems illustrated]

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you may want to change `list-style-position` to `inside` for the list itself. Otherwise, note that the numbers are *outside* of the element, so `margin: 0; padding: 0` would place those even further outside of container.

Comment: I've just tried adding that to the code, but then the second and third "aaa" in line 2 are not aligned, they get aligend with the bullets instead of the rest of the text.. so i'll need a complete solution...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your both problems can resolve with give styling to each li elements.

You just need to give them padding-left and this will be the distance of your text from the number.

To push all OL to the left use padding left with margin:0 to all the OL

Comment: I've just tried styling the li's, but padding left on them can only work to increase the space; in regards to the OL, zero margin still gets it out of the div...

Comment: Is outside of the div cause this is the default of the OL elements to put the number outside the OL, and also him parents elements.
you need to make the OL padding as you want the padding from the DIV. and LI's Padding as the space you want from text to number
Are you using reset CSS? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ this can resolve you problems like this.

Comment: I'm not using a CSS reset, I've just tried to and it didnt help... I didn't really understand the rest of your suggestion, I've tried modifying padding everywhere, nothing helped so far :/

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is with your html structure. You shouldn't have to use `<br>` elements inside a list. You also need some sort of reset to offset various default browser styles.

HTML

```
<div>
   <h1>Title</h1>
     <ol>
       <li>aaa</li>
       <li>aaa
        <ul>
         <li>aaa</li>
         <li>aaa</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      <li>aaa</li>
      <li>aaa</li>
     </ol>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
ol{
list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: .5em;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
ol li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul > li{
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Here it is in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fxx2j/

Comment: thanks, but regarding the margin between bullet and text - this does work on chrome,ff, and ie7, but not on ie8-10, they still render a big regular gap; regarding the extra "aaa", they are not items in the list, there's a <br> because it's basically a big paragraph, which is too big to get in one line; still i've tried your method but there are aligning differences for the second and third "aaa" between browsers.

Comment: which reset are you using? I would suggest normalize as it will get rid of discrepancies between browsers.